# Custom tags don't work in freemarker after updating to version 2.3.22

Tags: freemarker

I have used freemarker version 2.3.20. After updating it to 2.3.22 custom tags in ftl templates doesn't work any more. I am using next custom tag

```
 <#assign tg=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tld/tg.tld"]/> 
 <@tg.property key="common.oldBrowserSection.title.firefox"/>
```

After updating freemarker version to 2.3.23 I am receiving

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.NonUserDefinedDirectiveLikeException: For "@" callee: 
Expected a(n) user-defined directive, transform or macro, but this has evaluated to 
a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
tg.property  [in template "WEB INF/freemarker/common/warning/oldBrowserWarning.ftl" 
 at line 6, column 11]


 Tip: Maybe using obj.something(params) instead of obj.something will yield the 
 desired value

 FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: 
@tg.property key="common.oldBrowserS...  [in template "WEB-INF/freemarker/common/warning/oldBrowserWarning.ftl" 
at line 6, column 9]
```

Looks like problem in "@" symbol. Freemarker recognize it like macros. So my question is what is reason of this issue in new freemaker version and how to fix this without modifing all ftl templates (maybe change some configs).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
   <description>
       tag library
   </description>
   <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
   <short-name>tg</short-name>

   ....

    <tag>
    <description>propertyT</description>
    <name>property</name>
    <tag-class>tg.pack.custom.PropertyTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>key</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>canUseHtml</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>urlEncode</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>doProcessAttributes</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>escapeQuotes</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>escapeHtml</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>useUserEncode</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>js</name>
        <description>pass property to Javascript</description>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    </tag>

     ....

    </taglib>
```

function in tld:

```
    <function>
    <description>
        return localization value
    </description>
    <name>property</name>
    <function-class>td.app.customtag.Function</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        java.lang.String property(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
    </function-signature>
</function>
```

Comment: There was no change related to the interpretation of `@`, it was always used used like it is now. I suspect adding JSP EL function support made that change somehow. What's `property` in the TLD?

Comment: added tld to question

Comment: Don't you also have a `function` with the same name?

Comment: Yes I have function with name propery in my tld (added in question).

Comment: It's strange, why freemarker try to call function not my <@tg.property key="common.oldBrowserSection.title.firefox"/> tag ? When I remove @ looks like it works somehow but I prefer not to change all my templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when the EL function support was added to FreeMarker 2.3.22, it wasn't considered that you can have a custom tag and an EL function with the same name. And so the function overwrites the tag in FreeMarker's implementation, since FreeMarker doesn't have separate namespace for directives and functions. This will have to be addressed in the next version (2.3.25) somehow. For now, if the custom tag and the EL function have the same name, you can use `${tg.property("common.oldBrowserSection.title.firefox")}`.

Comment: This now fixed on Git. Until 2.3.25 is out (could be months), you can use this patch or just build and use the development version: https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/commit/c1d26de343756ca618b1fc4bc9e44d4611e141f6